Is there a way to convert HTML to XHTML within VBA Excel?
After some days of research, I've found that other tools outside Excel/VBA use XHTML to be able to use Xpath.
Selenium is not an option since for security reasons is not allowed to install programs (.exe), then I was
wondering if somebody knows if there is a microsoft library or how to convert from the HTML response in code below in line htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
to XHTML to be able to use Xpath expressions with SelectNodes() like in line Set elements = xhtmlDoc.SelectNodes("//body/div/div/div]")
Sub Html2Xhtml()
    Dim htmlDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elements As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim url as String

    url = "https://www.example.com"

    With New ServerXMLHTTP60
        .Open "Get", url, False
        .send
        htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    xhtmlDoc = SomeFunction(htmlDoc.body.innerHTML)
    
    Set elements = xhtmlDoc.SelectNodes("//body/div/div/div]")
    
End Sub


Maybe conversion from the html document to xhtml is not needed if you use queryselector or queryselectorall on the html document directly: htmldoc.queryselectorall("body > div > div > div")

@ShahramAlemzadeh thanks for answer, then thing is I need to search by text content and querySelectorAll() doesn´t allow me do that. And not sure why, Excel crashes if I try to debug opening the varuable that stores the output os querySelectorAll

@Fravadona, thanks for links share, but it seems is not exactly what I'm trying to do

@RasecMalkic, assign the result of the queryselector to a variable of type ihtmldomchildrencollection and loop thorought it as an array. Something like this : dim elements as ihtmldomchildrencollection : set elements= htmldoc.queryselectorall("body > div > div > div") : dim i as integer : for i=0 to elements.length-1 : process elements(i) here : next i
